# Add two data.frames, using rownames for index

Tags: r, dataframe

So how can I add two data frames, where the rows are added for identical row.names:

```
x = data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 10:1); y = x
rownames(y) = as.numeric(rownames(x)) + 5

x + y #WRONG, rows should be offset by '5', producing a data.frame that has 15 rows.
```

Can probably do it using ddply, by adding an index column, like this (which also shows the result I want):

```
x$id = as.numeric(rownames(x))
y$id = as.numeric(rownames(y))
plyr::ddply(rbind(x,y),'id',function(x){
  colSums(x[,c('x','y')])
})[,-1]
```

Target Result:

```
    x  y
1   1 10
2   2  9
3   3  8
4   4  7
5   5  6
6   7 15
7   9 13
8  11 11
9  13  9
10 15  7
11  6  5
12  7  4
13  8  3
14  9  2
15 10  1
```

In the above, rows 6:10 are the sum of the intersection of two dataframes, intersected by the index column.

Comment: This seems more like `join` than `add`. I strongly recommend against relying on row names to do much computation; some packages (e.g., `dplyr`) ignore/remove them, like it or leave it. It seems like you are using the row names as an index, so why not explicitly add a column, such as `$id`? In that case, you can use one of many joining techniques, such as `x$id <- 1:10; y$id <- 6:15; dplyr::bind_rows(x, dplyr::anti_join(y, x, by = "id"))`.

Comment: This would be easier handled using merge like `merge( x, y, by=0, all=TRUE)`.

Comment: People have guessed what you want, but it's definitely not adding. Please consider expanding, making your question clearer. Voting to close as is.

Comment: see my revised question

Answer (score 4):

Try this-

```
a <- rownames(x)
b <- rownames(y)
rbind(x[!(a %in% b),], x[intersect(a, b),] +
      y[intersect(a, b),], y[!(b %in% a),])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
# I would use aggregate
d <- aggregate(rbind.data.frame(x, y),
               list(rowname = c(rownames(x), rownames(y))),
               sum)
# if you want the rows ordered as before
d <- d[order(as.numeric(d$rowname)), ]

#    rowname  x  y
# 1        1  1 10
# 8        2  2  9
# 9        3  3  8
# 10       4  4  7
# 11       5  5  6
# 12       6  7 15
# 13       7  9 13
# 14       8 11 11
# 15       9 13  9
# 2       10 15  7
# 3       11  6  5
# 4       12  7  4
# 5       13  8  3
# 6       14  9  2
# 7       15 10  1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can merge by the row names which is generally not advisable. Then you get the indices of the same x's and y's and take a row sums.

```
xx=merge( x, y, by=0, all=TRUE)
l=lapply(names(x), function(yy) grep(paste('^',yy,'.*', sep = ''), names(xx) ))
df=as.data.frame(sapply(l, function(yy) rowSums(xx[,yy], na.rm = T)))
names(df)=names(x)
df[order(as.numeric(xx$Row.names)),]

    x  y
1   1 10
8   2  9
9   3  8
10  4  7
11  5  6
12  7 15
13  9 13
14 11 11
15 13  9
2  15  7
3   6  5
4   7  4
5   8  3
6   9  2
7  10  1
```